# Porting assembly code to c++

Tags: c++, assembly

I am porting assembly code to C++ and I have some problems porting a portion of it.

I have a pointer declared as:

```
void* function;
```

and it is pointing to a function call:

```
void* function = getfunction(lib, fname);
```

I have a inline assembly code which I have to migrate to C++:

```
__asm { call function }
```

How to call this pointer in C++?

Please note that the arguments `lib` and `fname` are of type `void*`.

And `void* function`  points to value returned by `getfunction()`.

Comment: What is the prototype of `getfunction` ?

Comment: "and it is pointing to a function call"? It's pointing to the result, that `getfunction` returns. Or I'm missing something big here..

Comment: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/78-function-pointers/

Comment: *And `void* function` points to value returned by `getfunction()`* That statement is in direct contradiction to the code immediately above. Where you wrote `function = getfunction(...)`. So, `function` is the value returned by `getfunction()`. Also, `lib` and `fname` are clearly going to be C strings. What makes you say that they are void*. Is this code decompiled? Do you have the original source?

Answer (score 1):

In what follows, I am assuming that the entire function call is encapsulated by

```
__asm { call function }
```

In which case this is a function pointer that can be declared like this:

```
void (*function)(void);
```

The `__asm` block does not push parameters onto the stack. Therefore the parameter list is empty. And the `__asm` block does not extract a return value. So the function has `void` return type.

You assign to the function pointer in just the same way:

```
function = getfunction(lib, fname);
```

And you call it like this:

```
function();
```

Comment: no, the pointer points to the value returened by that function call.

Comment: and "function();" returns an error2064: "term does not evaluate to function taking zero argument"

Comment: No, `function` is a function pointer. You can tell that because you issued `call function` on it. Also my code compiles. You presumably have still got `function` as `void*`. It should be declared as per my answer, `void (*function)(void);`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following example :

```
// ptrFunc is the name of the pointer to the getFunction
void* (*ptrFunc)(void*, void*) = &getfunction;
// ... Declaring whatever lib and fname are
// Now call the actual function by using a pointer to it
ptrFunc(lib, fname);
// Another form of how to call getFunc might be :
(*ptrFunc)(lib, fname);
```

Also, you can pass function pointers to another function such as :

```
void *getFunction(void* lib, void* fname)
{
   // Whatever
}

void myFunction( void* (*ptrFunc)(void*, void*) )
{
   // void *lib = something;
   // void *fname = something else;
   ptrFunc(lib, fname);
}

int main()
{
    void* (*ptrFunc)(void*, void*) = &getfunction;
    // Passing the actual function pointer to another function
    myFunction(ptrfunc);
}
```

Comment: If I'm not missing something, `getfunction` returns `void*` and `void* function` is not a function pointer, but a pointer to the result, returned from `getfunction`.

Comment: I must admit, i'm a bit confused about the question, as he said `and it is pointing to a function call`, so I wondered if what he really wants to use is a pointer to a function given that he asked `How to call this pointer ...`.

Comment: Yeah, I know. The question is not clear at all, it's very confusing and I can't really tell what OP wanted to ask.

Comment: Hey Kiril, you are right . this pointer points to the value returned by getfunction.

Comment: @KirilKirov If that is so, explain `__asm { call function }`. This has all the hallmarks of decompiled code. Why else is everything `void*`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I don't insist, I'm right. That was just my opinion. If I was sure, I'd write an answer, not a comment. But still - `void (*function)(void);` seems totally different to me than `void* function`, isn't it?

Comment: @Kiril Yes, but clearly these types are messed up. According to question update, everything is `void*`. And remember that all pointers are assignment compatible with `void*`.